# Flutter how to make the Container expand full height

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to expand the background color of the Container to take the full height.
I already tried to set the height to double infinite and that just gets rid of my Two Text Widgets Title and Lemon Chicken. This is the code its inside a Scalfold widget this part its only the body.

```
body: SingleChildScrollView(
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 36),
          child: GestureDetector(
            onTap: () => print('Add Image'),
            child: Icon(
              Icons.add_a_photo,
              size: 70,
              color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        Container(
          width: double.infinity,
          margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
              topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0),
              topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
            ),
            color: Colors.pink,
          ),
          child: Form(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(12.0),
              child: SingleChildScrollView(
                physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      'Title',
                      style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.black, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      'Lemon Chicken',
                      style:
                          TextStyle(color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    ),
  ),
```

This is the Image of my app.

[image]

I just want to expand the Widget has the pink background color

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use mediaquery to find device's height and set that as container's height

```
    Container(
      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height,
      width: double.infinity,
      margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 24),
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
          topLeft: Radius.circular(24.0),
          topRight: Radius.circular(24.0),
        ),
        color: Colors.pink,
      ),
```

or as you did you can use `double.infinity`

```
Container(
  height:double.infinity,
```

#### result:

[image]